# downloading lots of data and keeps my cpu busy right after start

Tags: release-loki, cpu

just have installed this OS (loki) and I really like it but there is a thing I am worry about.

I have noticed that something keeps downloading data and keeps my cpu busy right after start of system. System monitor showing me data usage and cpu activity (one of 4 cores always on 100%) even if I dont do anything. There is nothing in processes either. Every process shown has very low cpu usage. I used to have Ubuntu on my previous laptop with same programs installed and there was no such a problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I believe it checks for update packages when it starts up. Could this be it?

Comment: Please edit your comment to remove the Bluetooth question and post it separately. If the rough question is not in the title, it cannot be answered effectively.

Comment: I don't think it is packages update - I left the pc running for about 5 hours and over 3Gb was downloaded... Thank you anyway

Comment: In terminal you can type 'top' and you should see summary of processes, it should be same list, or 'ps -A' to view all processes. There has to be a process doing this, the underlying core is same as Ubuntu, it's only software above that level that is added by elementary, so it surely has to be visible somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it may be because of auto update performed by AppCenter. I noticed that too on my machine.

Here's how to disable these updates:
1. Kill AppCenter

```
`killall appcenter`
```

2.Show all the hidden startup applications

`sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`

3.launch Gnome Session Properties application

`gnome-session-properties`

4.Find AppCenter and uncheck it

Now it should update only when you'll click updates in AppCenter or via terminal with
`sudo apt-get update`
and
`sudo apt-get upgrade`
Commands

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem my cpu(celeron g1840) has usage 50% and more (not reported as a system process) because of network activity to sites like keeton.canonical.com, ftp.bit.nl and others.
This is what's happening:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:44458    ams15s30-in-f14.1e:http TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:36860    haetae.canonical.c:http TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:56900    stackoverflow.com:https ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:44448    ams15s30-in-f14.1e:http TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:39302    ftp.bit.nl:http         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:55386    keeton.canonical.c:http TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:36874    haetae.canonical.c:http TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:39326    ftp.bit.nl:http         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:39300    ftp.bit.nl:http         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.178.18:44582    ams15s30-in-f14.1e:http TIME_WAIT....
```

and:

```
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    16324    /run/user/1000/systemd/notify
unix  7      [ ]         DGRAM                    9851     /run/systemd/journal/socket
unix  18     [ ]         DGRAM                    9858     /run/systemd/journal/dev-log
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9862     /run/systemd/journal/syslog
unix  3      [ ]         SEQPACKET  CONNECTED     278774   @0001b
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    9844     /run/systemd/notify
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     672328   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17853    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     20773    /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     280847   
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     17269    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     73730    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     19760    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     670256   @/dbus-vfs-daemon/socket-w2sHGKfi
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     672329   @/dbus-vfs-daemon/socket-19luYW2N...
```

I tracked it down up to:

32411 _apt /usr/lib/apt/methods/http enp2s0 0.572 20.516 KB/sec

31916 _apt /usr/lib/apt/methods/http enp2s0 0.547 20.490 KB/sec

The appcenter is indeed causing the problem, the solution to stop the appcenter from auto starting worked for my system.

Comment: Does a `apt update` work normal for you? Maybe open an issue on the appcenter repository? https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/